# Photos app on macOS doesn't upload any photos ("Sync session in push got error")

Tags: icloud, photos

I want to upload around 20k of photos in a complete new Photos iCloud library. However, the app stops uploading after around 900 images.

With the command

```
 log stream --style syslog --predicate '(subsystem beginswith[cd] "com.apple.photos.cpl")'
```

I am getting the following output:

```
Filtering the log data using "subsystem BEGINSWITH[cd] "com.apple.photos.cpl""
Timestamp                       (process)[PID]
2022-02-06 06:41:06.170173+0100  localhost cloudphotod[23545]: (CloudPhotoLibrary) [com.apple.photos.cpl:engine.resourcestorage.filestorage] Unable to store the crash recovery file to <private>
2022-02-06 06:41:06.176237+0100  localhost cloudphotod[23545]: [com.apple.photos.cpl:engine.resourcestorage.filestorage.bucket] Failed to store <private> to <private>: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=24 UserInfo={NSURL=<private>, NSLocalizedDescription=<private>}
2022-02-06 06:41:06.176663+0100  localhost cloudphotod[23545]: (CloudPhotoLibrary) [com.apple.photos.cpl:engine.resourcestorage.filestorage] Unable to remove crash recovery file: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 UserInfo={NSUserStringVariant=<private>, NSFilePath=<private>, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fc5f69d2820 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
2022-02-06 06:41:06.176705+0100  localhost cloudphotod[23545]: (CloudPhotoLibrary) [com.apple.photos.cpl:engine.resourcestorage.filestorage] Error storing file: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=24 UserInfo={NSURL=<private>, NSLocalizedDescription=<private>}
2022-02-06 06:41:06.176757+0100  localhost cloudphotod[23545]: (CloudPhotoLibrary) [com.apple.photos.cpl:engine.resourcestorage] Unable to store [Original for AQrzl/8MNwlfKv70Lxat1RSozi0l#PrimarySync(1) (AQrzl/8MNwlfKv70Lxat1RSozi0l - public.jpeg) file: <redacted>] (<private>): Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=24 UserInfo={NSURL=<private>, NSLocalizedDescription=<private>}
2022-02-06 06:41:06.176867+0100  localhost cloudphotod[23545]: (CloudPhotoLibrary) [com.apple.photos.cpl:engine.store.transactions] ! [TRANSACTION [WRITE] cpl.store.write] failed: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=24 UserInfo={NSURL=<private>, NSLocalizedDescription=<private>}
2022-02-06 06:41:06.177441+0100  localhost photolibraryd[794]: (PhotoLibraryServices) [com.apple.photos.cpl:client.assetsd.manager.systemlibrary] Got a commit error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=24 UserInfo={NSURL=<private>, NSLocalizedDescription=<private>}
2022-02-06 06:41:06.179154+0100  localhost photolibraryd[794]: (PhotoLibraryServices) [com.apple.photos.cpl:client.assetsd.manager.systemlibrary] Tasks: (null)
2022-02-06 06:41:06.179291+0100  localhost photolibraryd[794]: (PhotoLibraryServices) [com.apple.photos.cpl:client.assetsd.manager.systemlibrary] Received error while upload batch: <CPLChangeBatch [CPLMasterChange: +1/0/-0, CPLAssetChange: +1/0/-0] {{
  <CPLMasterChange AQrzl/8MNwlfKv70Lxat1RSozi0l#PrimarySync [A]>,
  <CPLAssetChange 30532A7B-8C45-41AA-995C-3C4992031432#PrimarySync [A]>
}}>: Error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=24 UserInfo={NSURL=<private>, NSLocalizedDescription=<private>}
2022-02-06 06:41:06.183902+0100  localhost photolibraryd[794]: (PhotoLibraryServices) [com.apple.photos.cpl:client.assetsd] Batch retry count: 2
2022-02-06 06:41:06.186242+0100  localhost photolibraryd[794]: (PhotoLibraryServices) [com.apple.photos.cpl:client.assetsd] Batch exceeded max retry count: 2 for permanent failure, marking as failed
2022-02-06 06:41:06.203950+0100  localhost photolibraryd[794]: (PhotoLibraryServices) [com.apple.photos.cpl:client.assetsd.manager.systemlibrary] Waiting 5 seconds then retrying upload after error processing batch
```

And

```
 2022-02-06 16:14:01.496 E  cloudphotod[78070:1849e5] [com.apple.photos.cpl:engine.syncmanager.lasterror] Sync session in push got error: Error Domain=CloudPhotoLibraryErrorDomain Code=81 UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=<private>, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe2fbafc950 {Error Domain=CKErrorDomain Code=35 UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=<private>, CKErrorDescription=<private>, NSFilePath=<private>, NSDebugDescription=<private>, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe2fba86ee0 {Error Domain=CKInternalErrorDomain Code=3010 UserInfo={NSFilePath=<private>, NSLocalizedDescription=<private>, CKErrorDescription=<private>}}}}}, underlying error: Error Domain=CKErrorDomain Code=35 UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=<private>, CKErrorDescription=<private>, NSFilePath=<private>, NSDebugDescription=<private>, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe2fba86ee0 {Error Domain=CKInternalErrorDomain Code=3010 UserInfo={NSFilePath=<private>, NSLocalizedDescription=<private>, CKErrorDescription=<private>}}}
```

I delete the iCloud Photos library locally on my Mac multiple times, readded the photos and then activated iCloud again, but still, it always just works for the first 900 photos. I have still ~150GB of free storage on my iCloud account as well.

Is there any other way of uploading the photos? How can I batch/mass upload photos to iCloud?

Comment: Where are these 20K photos and your Photos library currently located (On Mac or external drive)? How much free space on your Mac?

Answer (score 1):

It appears all of Apple's photo daemons and general iCloud syncing occur in batches of ~900 items. While the start/stops of the batches are a little erratic (a few seconds apart, up to an hour). I do find that the system eventually chews through everything. It certainly would be nice to be able to tell the system to accelerate through to the end.